# Remove html tags from Image Title and Alt attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a client using a CMS and the title and alt image attributes are being pulled in from the title.  Most titles have html in then (span and br tags).  I need to remove the html tags from the title and alt text from the following example code?

```
<ul class="products">
    <li><img src="images/product_image_1" title="<span>Company Name</span> First Product<br /> Name" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/product_image_2" title="<span>Company Name</span> Second Product<br /> Name" /></li>
</ul>
```

I need it to look like this:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li><img src="images/product_image_1" title="Company Name First Product Name" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/product_image_2" title="Company Name Second Product Name" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The CMS (whatever it is) *should* have some functionality to achieve this automatically.

Comment: The problem is that it comes from a plugin and they don't want me to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// iterate over each of the <img> elements that have a
// title attribute:
$('ul li img[title]').each(function() {
  // set the title of the current <img> to
  // the text returned from a dummy <div> element,
  // after setting its html to that of the title attribute:
  this.title = $('<div />', {
    'html': this.title
  // finding the text of that created-<div>:
  }).text();
});
```

```js
$('ul li img[title]').each(function() {
  this.title = $('<div />', {
    'html': this.title
  }).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife" title="<span>Company Name</span> First Product<br /> Name" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" title="<span>Company Name</span> Second Product<br /> Name" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I spent way too much time trying to figure this out and over complicating it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy HTML element (never actually added to the document).

Set its HTML to the contents of each `img title`, then set the title back to the element's `text()` content.

```js
var dummy = $('<p>');

$('.products img[title]').each(
   function() {
     var img = $(this);
     dummy.html( img.attr('title') );
     img.attr( 'title', dummy.text() );
   }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
    <li><img src="images/product_image_1" title="<span>Company Name</span> First Product<br /> Name" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/product_image_2" title="<span>Company Name</span> Second Product<br /> Name" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `replace` in javascript to find the `br` tags and remove them:

You would have to first give id's to your list elements.

```
var str = document.getElementById( 'listElement1' ).innerHTML;
var res = str.replace( '<br />', '' );
```

Then do the same with the `span` elements.

```
var res = str.replace( '<span>Company Name</span>', '' );
```